# Splash Screen In Windows 7 using cordova

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, splash-screen

I'm using Visual Stdio 2010 And Phone Gap 2.9.0 version .

I want to Change My Default Splash Screen with my new image in Windows 7 Mobile App.

How to do this ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the image with the same name (i.e SplashScreenImage.jpg) as well as same dimensions i.e 480x800.

Hope it helps